# Combine and do calculation two vectors return map Clojure

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure, zipmap

I got two vectors, `[shoes milk shoes]` and `[1 3 1]`, and the map I want to get is `{shoes 2, milk 3}`. I tried to `zipmap` two vectors and only `{shoes 1 milk 3}` shows. Without loop and iterate, is there another way to do that?

Comment: The vectors are not fixed. Maybe [shoes milk milk] or [shoes milk milk shoes flower]. Also corresponding vectors changed also

Comment: Please add this information to your question so more people can see it. Not everyone will look at comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can also employ a bit different solution for that, generating one-entry maps for item-to-amount pair, and then merging them with `+`:

```
(let [goods '[shoes milk shoes]
      amounts [1 3 1]]
  (apply merge-with + (map hash-map goods amounts)))

;;=> {milk 3, shoes 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a `reduce`:

- build up tuples of key/value from your two lists
- accumulate into a map: add the value to the value for the key in the map (or start from 0 if missing (nil is passed))

```clj
(let [v1 '[shoes milk shoes]              
      v2 [1 3 1]] 
  (reduce                                                                 
    (fn [m [k v]]                                                   
      (update m k (fnil + 0) v))                        
    {}                     
    (map vector v1 v2)))
; → {shoes 2, milk 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked the solution of @leetwinski a lot.

Actually, to solve similar problems in future,
I would suggest, first to collect the values of all keys in lists - in their occurring order:

```
(defn vecs2hash 
  [keys values]
  (apply merge-with concat (map (fn [k v] {k (list v)}) keys values)))
```

Then:

```
(def hm (vecs2hash '[shoes milk shoes milk] [1 4 2 3]))

hm
;; => {milk (4 3), shoes (1 2)}
```

Then, one could write a function dealing with each of the collected elements as you wish.

Define a new function to sum up all values in the list:

```
(defn sum-up-value
  [val]
  (apply + val))
```

Define a helper function to apply the helper function to process all value-lists:

```
(defn apply-to-each-value
  [fun hm]
  (apply hash-map (interleave (keys hm) (map fun (vals hm)))))
```

So in your case:

```
(apply-to-each-value sum-up-values hm)
;; {milk 7, shoes 3}
```

Comment: `flatten` is almost never good, when you're not sure what the `values` type is: `(vecs2hash [:a :b :a] [[1 2] [2 3] [3 4]])` => `{:b ([2 3]), :a (1 2 3 4)}`. i would propose this one: `(defn vecs2hash [keys values] (apply merge-with concat (map (fn [k v] {k [v]}) keys values)))`